# How to correctly define Node.js functions and properties for Prepack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prepack

I want to use `prepack` on my NPM package, but i getting errors like `require is not defined`, and `module is not defined`.

I tried to define this variables like:

```
__assumeDataProperty(global, 'require', __abstract('function'))
```

but i getting error `unknown reference type`

How can i can correctly define `Node.js` global functions and properties for `prepack`?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Use compatibility mode `node-cli`

```
$ prepack sourcefile.js --compatibility node-cli
```

However as of now it is available only on [Node 7.9](https://github.com/facebook/prepack/blob/master/src/prepack-node-environment.js#L48-L53).

Here's the explanation for that:

By declaring `require` as `__abstract('function')` you have informed prepack that require is a function, but now what it returns. Modelling the environment correctly would mean you need to correctly declare what `require` would return. But as you'd guess, this is not easy: every require call returns a different object depending upon the module being required.

This basically means you have to follow through the entire module loading mechanism to figure out what the shape of each object is that is being returned by all the requires and that exactly what [this commit does](https://github.com/facebook/prepack/commit/f6ce5c357908460cdf18eb6ca84f2e06adaa8010). However, since the PR was more of a PoC than a complete feature by itself, the author had to use some of Node's private APIs which tend to change between release. Hence this experimental feature is available only on Node 7.9 for now.

Hope this helps :)